# jQuery Countdown server sync classic ASP

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

Ive been using keith woods countdown.

im using it with  a classic asp auction setup

my problem is i need the time synced i can see the code for PHP but cant seem to get it going for ASP

```
   $(selector).countdown({
       until: liftoffTime,
       serverSync: serverTime
   });

   function serverTime() {
       var time = null;
       $.ajax({
           url: 'http://myserver.com/serverTime.php',
           async: false,
           dataType: 'text',
           success: function (text) {
               time = new Date(text);
           },
           error: function (http, message, exc) {
               time = new Date();
           }
       });
       return time;
   }

    <? php
    $now = new DateTime();
   echo $now - > format("M j, Y H:i:s O").
   "\n"; ?>
```

any help converting would be great?

Comment: Just to confirm, you're talking about Classic ASP/VB-Script, *not* ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about classic ASP indeed and not ASP.NET, try something like this:

```
<%
    Dim dt
    dt = Now()
    Response.Write MonthName(Month(dt),True) & " " & Day(dt) & ", " & Year(dt) & " " & Right("0" & Hour(dt), 2) & ":" & Right("0" & Minute(dt), 2) & ":" & Right("0" & Second(dt), 2) & vbLf
%>
```